# How I can use generated headers (like from messages) from one package in another?

Tags: ros, catkin, header, messages, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using groovy + catkin.
How can I include the devel/include<package_name>, which contains e.g. the generated header-files from the messages in another package?

```
find_package(package_name REQUIRED)
```

and

```
include_directories(include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${merlin_messages_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

doesn't seem to be enough, I suppose that this include only the headers which come from this package, but not the automatically generated one?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52002/how-i-can-use-generated-headers-(like-from-messages)-from-one-package-in-another?/) by [mifritscher](https://answers.ros.org/users/3945/mifritscher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The code you posted is sufficient for finding headers, as message headers are generated to the same location that your others headers go to.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1